# How to create variable accessible by multiple classes and multiple methods in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to create a global variable in my Java program, or at least one that can be accessed by multiple methods of multiple classes.  I'm fluent in C, VB6, Jovial, and many other languages, but I don't get Java.  I chose it ONLY for WindowBuilder!

Here is some Java-like pseudocode for what I want, minimal to show what I am trying to do.  I am aware that it doesn't compile as-is; the point I am focusing on is the `NumberOfMembers` variable -- how it should be declared and accessed:

```
public class Prelim {
    public String FileName;
    public int NumberOfMembers;  //instantiate?  I've tried all I know
    //to do so!  Instantiate where, all methods that use?

    private void myMethod_a() {
        FileName = "C:\myfilename";
        ReadRoster();
        //modify roster
        WriteRoster();
        System.out.println(NumberOfMembers);
    }


}

public class ReadWriteRoster /* maybe extends Prelim?? */ {  
    public void ReadRoster(){
        //read roster file using FileName
        NumberOfMembers = 100;
    }
    public void WriteRoster(){
       //write roster file using FileName
        for (int num = 0; num < NumberOfMembers; num++){
        }
        //do the write`enter code here`
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: took me 1.5 minutes to find this: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090403100850AAGxL2l

Comment: Please format the code in your post so people can read it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "static" key Word example

static int i = 3;

With this you can access to the variable i in all class of The package and you can import this in all other package.

Answer (score 1):

Java does not offer global variables in the same sense that C and some other languages do.  Every variable is associated with a specific class, and often with a particular instance of that class.  These two alternatives are distinguished by use of the `static` keyword, which indicates that the variable (or method or nested class) is associated only with its host class, not with any particular object of that class.

Probably the simplest way to achieve what you *asked* starts with declaring `NumberOfMembers` statically, like so:

```
public class Prelim {
    // ...
    public static int NumberOfMembers;
    // ...
}
```

Then, everywhere you want to reference it in any other class, you need to qualify its name with the class to tell Java which variable of that name you mean:

```
    // ...
    Prelim.NumberOfMembers = 100;
    // ...
```

Although it is not strictly necessary, as a matter of style I recommend using the qualified form even inside the host class.

With that said, what little I see of your code underscores your admission that you don't get Java.  Classes should represent *things*, and to reinforce that to yourself and others, their names should be nouns or noun phrases.

You seem instead to be organizing your classes around steps in your processing algorithm.  This leads to a pretty arbitrary arrangement of your code, and directly to some of the questions in code comments about instantiating class `Prelim`.  You are trying to write procedural code, but dressing it up in object-oriented form.  You can write procedural code in Java, but it is likely that your task would accommodate a bona fide object-oriented approach as well.

At first glance, an object-oriented version of your code might involve turning it inside out: it looks like it at least wants a class `Roster` with an instance variable `numberOfMembers` and methods `read()` and `write()`.  Those methods could refer to the instance variable naturally, because they would be referring to a member variable *of the same object*.  That would also better accommodate having multiple rosters in the program at the same time, each with its own number of members.

Answer (score 0):

More complex example is using enum types. It is a good practice using enum as singleton.